# Difference in evenness

Tags: c++

Ok, so this code is supposed to print out the index number of the array in which it differs in evenness. For example, I have a list of numbers: 2,4,6,7,8. So 7 differs in evenness so it should print out the index of 7. Indexing starts from 1 so it should print out 4 in this case.

I tried the following code but when I submit it online it says runtime error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n, i, index, even = 0, odd = 0;

    cin >> n;

    int a[100];

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];

        if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
            even++;
        } else {
            odd++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (even > odd) {
            if (a[i] % 2 == 1) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << index;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "indexing starts from 1" - that is just making life difficult for yourselef - it should start at zero.

Comment: **Can not reproduce**: [ideone](https://ideone.com/Sd2G7u).

Comment: @scohe001 i bet it could be reproduced with `n=100`  or bigger, though I am too lazy to type all the input

Comment: @user463035818 Ahh perhaps. But "I put my code into a black box and it says I'm wrong. Can you help me?" is not a valid SO question. Unless they can give "a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it," this looks off-topic to me.

Comment: btw you could get the result in a single pass, then you wouldnt need the array

Comment: If you're guaranteed that only one number is "off", you know the "good evenness" after three numbers and don't need the array.

Comment: @scohe001 acutally I do agree. Such "please tell me why my code does not produce correct output even I do not know what is correct output" questions are not of great value to anybody.. just felt like answering this one ;)

Comment: Based on `I tried the following code but when I submit it online it says runtime error` i assume, that this online exercise provides more information, e.g. a maximum number of elements your code should be able to work with. This information is missing in your question.

Comment: Are you trying to find the first odd number?  If so, there is no reason for incrementing the quantity of odd or evens.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] indexing starts from 1 [...]

No it does not. In your code you consitently use indices from 1 up to size of the array, but valid indices are 0 till size-1.

This loop:

```
for(i = 1;i<=n;i++)
{
   cin >> a[i];

   if(a[i]%2==0)
   {
       even++;
   }
   else
   {
       odd++;
   }   
}
```

can be easily made to invoke undefined behaviour when `n==100` or bigger (because `a[100]` is out of bounds).

If the task requires you to use indexing starting with 1, then you should still use the correct indexing and only for the final result add 1.